# Flash input text box background on button click

Tags: css

I have an input text box and a button element. I want text box background color fade in and fade out with a click of a button.

HTML

```
<input type="text">
<button>Click</button>
```

CSS

```
input{
   transition: background-color 0.1s ease-in-out 0s;
}
input:target{
    background-color: red;
}
```

I can't figure out how to trigger the animation on the button click.

Here is a gif of the desired effect

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjY1Z.gif

*Edit* Originally I asked about accomplishing this without javascript, but it appears that it is not possible.

Comment: This was likely done with like **element:selection{background:#FFFFFF; /*Some Color Code*/}** and **element:focus{border: 1px solid rgb(255,255,255) /*Some Color Code -- Could also use the outline effect*/}**, However, they probably used JS to select it when the button was clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please try this working example on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9j826bcb/5/

I used CSS3 Animations here.

```
@keyframes highlight {
  50%  {background-color: green;}
  100% { background-color: white; }
}

input {
  outline: 0;
}

input.active {
  background-color: white;
  animation-name: highlight;
  animation-duration: .1s;
}

input.final {
  border:1px solid green;
}

input.final::selection {
  background: green;
}

input.final::-moz-selection {
  background: green; 
}
```

Also, please note that you will have to include jQuery into your project source, and trigger 'click' action:

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('input').addClass('active');
  }, 100);

  $('input').removeClass('active').addClass('final').trigger('focus').select();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Toggle a class on click, and use an `animation` associated with the class to do the flash effect.

Not sure why this isn't working in my comment, but here's a codepen - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BpMpYe

```js
var button = document.getElementById('button'),
    input = document.getElementById('input'),
    flashClass = 'flash';

button.addEventListener('click',function() {
  input.classList.add(flashClass);
});

input.addEventListener('animationend',function() {
  this.classList.remove(flashClass);
});
```

```css
.flash {
  animation: flash .15s;
}

@keyframes flash {
  50% {
    background: green;
  }
  100% {
    background: transparent;
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="input" type="text">
<button id="button">Click</button>
```